# What is the difference between "sparkle" and "spark" as nouns?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Is my following understanding accurate?

As nouns, spark connotes a small flash of light, whereas sparkle connotes a series of flashes of light, shining brightly.

1,**The performance lacked sparkle.**
This means the performance lacked the quality of being lively and original.

2,**The performance lacked spark.**
This means the performance lacked the quality of energy, intelligence or enthusiasm.

3,**The writer lacked creative spark.**
This means the writer didn’t have even a small amount of creativity.

4,**The writer lacked creative sparkle.**
This means the writer didn’t have a large amount of creativity.

---

My new analysis:

Spark is the more common and natural word choice in the above two cases, because
(a)spark is more often used metaphorically and conveys a clearer meaning there, whereas sparkle is more often used literally
(b)spark is a more common word, giving readers a feeling of familiarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your analysis of 1 and 2.

For 3 and 4, I would say that the **creative spark** is the thing a writer has that is the opposite of **writer's block**, i.e. "creative spark" is the idea within the writer they are trying to get out on paper, or perhaps could be used to describe a writer who has no problem coming up with new ideas. **Creative sparkle** would be the *extra* quality of "flair" or "zest" that could liven up a narrative just as you describe for your sentence 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarification. It helps a lot. Can you evaluate "My new analysis" that I just added to the question?

Comment: @joy2020, I agree that "spark" is more often used as a *metaphor* and "sparkle" more often as a *simile* (or perhaps *stand-in*—we don't say that a performance **literally** sparkled but we talk about it as if it did). I wouldn't agree that readers are more familiar with one over the other; both are commonly used.